# addListener Проблема непроверяет функцию, пока не будет движения зуммера

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Есть код :

```
var mapOptions = {  zoom: 12, center: new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Lng) }
var MARKER = new MarkerWithLabel({ map: map, ...});
var CENTER = new MarkerWithLabel({ map: map, ...}); // jquery 3.3.1

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() { 
  var zoomen = map.getZoom(); 
  MARKER.setVisible(zoomen >= 15 && zoomen <= 17); // все тут работает, но не при первом запуске карты!
  CENTER.setVisible(zoomen < 15); // Меняют zoom, и MARKER пропадает, хотя его и не должно быть!
}
```

Проблема в том, что метки все равно показываются на экране, хотя есть функция для их фильтрации. Фильтрация работает лишь тогда, когда я меняю zoom. Читал что нужно использовать не addListener, а addListenerOnce, но тоже не работает! Так же видел комментарий, что это происходит из-за слушателя zoom_changed. Возможно это чем то поможет. Прошу помочь, никак ответ найти не могу, как решается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var mapOptions = {  zoom: 12, center: new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Lng) }
var MARKER = new MarkerWithLabel({ map: map, ...});
var CENTER = new MarkerWithLabel({ map: map, ...});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', zoomChange);
zoomChange();

function zoomChange() {
  var zoomen = map.getZoom(); 
  MARKER.setVisible(zoomen >= 15 && zoomen <= 17);      
  CENTER.setVisible(zoomen < 15); 
}
```

> объяснение этому решению

В Вашем коде Вы только прикрепляете обработчик события к карте, но не вызываете его. Может быть, у карты есть метод для вызова событий, что-то вроде:

```
var mapOptions = {  zoom: 12, center: new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Lng) }
var MARKER = new MarkerWithLabel({ map: map, ...});
var CENTER = new MarkerWithLabel({ map: map, ...});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
  var zoomen = map.getZoom(); 
  MARKER.setVisible(zoomen >= 15 && zoomen <= 17);      
  CENTER.setVisible(zoomen < 15); 
});
map.trigger(new Event("zoom_changed")); // ???
```

Тогда можно обойтись без именованой функции.

Comment: Большое спасибо за быстрый ответ! :) Все работает. 
 А есть объяснение этому решению, почему приходится создавать эту штуку "name_function();", чего она без него не работает? Если не утруждаю ^ ^

Comment: Cпасибо за полный ответ! Все понял, раньше не знал, программирую на js не более месяца уже, и как то не доводилось сталкиваться с этой проблемой :)

Comment: @ValeriiValeriyovich Пожалуйста. Успехов!